# PDF submit form calling a servlet and receiving another pdf

Tags: java, pdf, servlets, itext, acrobat

I have a `pdf` document created with `itext`.
This is a `fillable pdf` with a submit button that send filled data to a `servlet`.
The `servlet` store the data in a database and return the same `pdf` without any fillable field so it's ready to be sent to any client.

Everything works fine but acrobat save that file in a `tmp` folder with a tmp name, not the name that I specify in the `servlet` response.

It's possible to force the file name?

Thanks to all!

S

Comment: You can avoid that problem by modifying your workflow. You actually don't need Acrobat to save the form at all. Try submitting *just the data* to your servlet then use iText to merge the data with a server-based copy of the form then flatten it and return that PDF to the client.

Comment: maybe I explained wrong.
what you say is exactly what I do.
The problem is that the servlet returns the pdf ready for sending to clients but does not use the name I assigned to it. The name is a "series of random characters".tmp

Comment: Ah. Ok. You'd set the filename of the downloaded file in the response header. You don't show any code so I can't give an exact response but this is the kind of thing that'd go in the Java HttpServletResponse header. "Content-disposition","attachment; filename=yourfilename.pdf"

Comment: Thank you very much for the support. I already se the header: resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName);
   resp.getOutputStream().write( finalData); but acrobat change the final name in a temp name :-(

Comment: It's probably not Acrobat then, I'm guessing the browser that's executing the download isn't respecting the header.

Comment: the is no browser... I open the PDF by Acrobat, I fill a form and I press the submitbutton that send data to the servlet. The servlet response a PDF..

Comment: I see. In that case Acrobat would ignore the filename. Instead of returning a PDF though, you need to return an FDF that has it's F/ key set to the fully qualified path to the new PDF. You can find more information on the FDF toolkit here... http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/fdftoolkit.html